# Loading screen in window.open via electron

Tags: javascript, electron

I wanted to show loading screen in electron js when window.open is opening some url.

example : `window.open("https://example.com");`

```
  window.webContents.on("new-window", (event, url) => {
    // there are more args not used here
    event.preventDefault();

    loading = new BrowserWindow({ width: 300, height: 300, transparent: true, frame: false, alwaysOnTop: true });
    loading.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/splash.html`);

    const win = new BrowserWindow({ show: false, width: 1200, height: 1000 });
    win.webContents.once("dom-ready", () => {
      win.show();
      loading.hide(); // don't destroy in this case
    });
    win.loadURL(url);
    loading.show();
    event.newGuest = win;
  });
```

I tried above code and its working fine , except for some site is losing cookies/session when opened popup via new Browserwindow.. can i just get dom-ready callback on window.open() directly... so i can hide my loading screen...

basically i just want to window.open to open windows normally and want loading screen to be shown until pages are loaded

```
const win = new BrowserWindow({ show: false, width: 1200, height: 1000 });
```

Comment: You must be on an old version of Electron, because I'm pretty sure the `new-window` event has been removed. It might be nice to upgrade if it's feasible. Who knows if the issue you're running into has been fixed in the latest versions

Comment: I don't totally get what you mean the site is losing session/cookies? Could you just show the window (so don't `preventDefault()`, but overlay a BrowserView ontop of it with the loading screen until the page has loaded?

Comment: hi , yes i upgraded to new electron... and what i meant losing session is , I have a external webpage in which once its logged in, it loses its session even when i opened it in new tab of same window.. so i have to log in again... but with window.open it was some how maintaining its session.. but in the example code i gave above.. since it creates new browser window , its again asking me to login.

Comment: That's odd. I thought my default windows will share the default session unless you explicitly specify a new one via the `session` property of `BrowserWindow`